# how to get the time of the video player which is equivalent the input type range

Tags: javascript, html5-video

I am creating a video player and I want to create a function which will show the video time which is equivalent input range hovered part.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ju7aC.png)

I created a function, but it gives me not accurate time.

```
function getHoveredTime(e) {

    const time = e.offsetX * video.duration / e.target.getBoundingClientRect().width;

    const min = Math.floor(time / 60);
    const sec = Math.floor(time - min * 60);

    return min + ':' + sec;
}
```

Comment: What is mean by equivalent input range when i hover on input range.

Answer (score 0):

The logic to calculate `min` and `sec` is incorrect, consider the following code.

```
function getHoveredTime(e) {
    const scale = e.offsetX / e.target.getBoundingClientRect().width;
    const time = parseInt(video.duration * scale);
    const min = parseInt(time / 60);
    const sec = time % 60;    
    return min + ':' + sec;
}
```

**Update**

The problem is because the "scale" is being rounded.
https://jsfiddle.net/73wubmxr/

Comment: Thank you, but it gives me not accurate time.
For example it return me 0:18 but when i click on range video current time = 0:16

Comment: it should work technically since you are just scaling the video.duration based on the offset and getting the time. The only place you could try tweaking may be `e.offsetX` since everything else is a constant

Comment: Can you share a jsfiddle of the code to reproduce the error? I am not sure what exactly is your issue

Comment: Do you know another way to get the time?